# Cannot remove duplicated Android 6.0.0 Clang compilers kits auto-detected in Qt6

Tags: c++, qt, qml, clang, qt6

Problem 1:

I'm using Windows 10 Home. I have installed Qt6, Android Studio 2019, and Visual Studio 2019. Before installing Visual Studio 2019, Qt6 was working fine, but since I have installed Visual Studio 2019, there are now duplicated compilers in Qt6 for all Android 6.0.0 Clang kits (please see screenshot). Can someone tell me how to removed the duplicated ones? The Remove buttons are all greyed out.  Why does Qt6 auto-detect more than one of the same compiler?

The duplicated compilers under Auto-Detect are:

- Android Qt 6.0.0 Clang arm64-v8a
- Android Qt 6.0.0 Clang armeabi-v7a
- Android Qt 6.0.0 Clang x86
- Android Qt 6.0.0 Clang x86_64

Qt6 have auto-detected identical instances three of each, and the remove option for all of them are greyed out.

[image: Duplicated compilers]

[image: Duplicated compilers cannot be removed(greyed out)]

Problem 2:

Once openned a project example (ie. Coffee machine, the default example project that comes with Qt6 installation), in the General Messages (Alt + 6) of Qt6, it shows the following:

```
2021-01-12T18:19:28 Clang Code Model: Error: The clangbackend executable "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\clangbackend.exe" could not be started (timeout after 10000ms).
QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.

Module path: C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Basic
See "Using QML Modules with Plugins" in the documentation.

Automatic type dump of QML module failed.
Errors:
"C:\Qt\6.0.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" returned exit code 3.
Arguments: -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Controls.Basic 2.0 .
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/loaddependencies.qml: Module namespace 'QtQuick.Controls' does not match import URI ''


QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.

Module path: C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Basic
See "Using QML Modules with Plugins" in the documentation.

Automatic type dump of QML module failed.
Errors:
"C:\Qt\6.0.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" returned exit code 3.
Arguments: -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Controls.Basic 2.0 .
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/loaddependencies.qml: Module namespace 'QtQuick.Controls' does not match import URI ''


QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.

Module path: C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Fusion
See "Using QML Modules with Plugins" in the documentation.

Automatic type dump of QML module failed.
Errors:
"C:\Qt\6.0.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" returned exit code 3.
Arguments: -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Controls.Fusion 2.0 .
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/loaddependencies.qml: Module namespace 'QtQuick.Controls' does not match import URI ''


QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.

Module path: C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Imagine
See "Using QML Modules with Plugins" in the documentation.

Automatic type dump of QML module failed.
Errors:
"C:\Qt\6.0.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" returned exit code 3.
Arguments: -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Controls.Imagine 2.0 .
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/loaddependencies.qml: Module namespace 'QtQuick.Controls' does not match import URI ''


QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.

Module path: C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Universal
See "Using QML Modules with Plugins" in the documentation.

Automatic type dump of QML module failed.
Errors:
"C:\Qt\6.0.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" returned exit code 3.
Arguments: -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0 .
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/loaddependencies.qml: Module namespace 'QtQuick.Controls' does not match import URI ''


QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.

Module path: C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Imagine
See "Using QML Modules with Plugins" in the documentation.

Automatic type dump of QML module failed.
Errors:
"C:\Qt\6.0.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" returned exit code 3.
Arguments: -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Controls.Imagine 2.0 .
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/loaddependencies.qml: Module namespace 'QtQuick.Controls' does not match import URI ''


QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.

Module path: C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Material
See "Using QML Modules with Plugins" in the documentation.

Automatic type dump of QML module failed.
Errors:
"C:\Qt\6.0.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" returned exit code 3.
Arguments: -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0 .
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/loaddependencies.qml: Module namespace 'QtQuick.Controls' does not match import URI ''


QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.

Module path: C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Material
See "Using QML Modules with Plugins" in the documentation.

Automatic type dump of QML module failed.
Errors:
"C:\Qt\6.0.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" returned exit code 3.
Arguments: -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0 .
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/loaddependencies.qml: Module namespace 'QtQuick.Controls' does not match import URI ''


QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.

Module path: C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Universal
See "Using QML Modules with Plugins" in the documentation.

Automatic type dump of QML module failed.
Errors:
"C:\Qt\6.0.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" returned exit code 3.
Arguments: -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0 .
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/loaddependencies.qml: Module namespace 'QtQuick.Controls' does not match import URI ''


QML module does not contain information about components contained in plugins.

Module path: C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Fusion
See "Using QML Modules with Plugins" in the documentation.

Automatic type dump of QML module failed.
Errors:
"C:\Qt\6.0.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlplugindump.exe" returned exit code 3.
Arguments: -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Controls.Fusion 2.0 .
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/loaddependencies.qml: Module namespace 'QtQuick.Controls' does not match import URI ''
```

Can someone please explain what is happening and what should I do to correct those errors?
I could not find any answers by Googling so far. Has anyone encountered similar problems before?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. It happened after deleting NDK version manually or via Android Studio. Since Qt requires specific Ndk version for each Qt version([table here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-getting-started.html#android-ndk)), you **have to reinstall** NDK through Qt options tools. This process strangely adds another auto detected kit and does not override the old one.

Solution is to delete unnecessary kits from the `profiles.xml`. You can easily find it under:

```
C:\Users\**current_user**\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator
```

To decide which one to delete I did this:

1. Checkout the compilers and debuggers. As you can see the image, the second one will work since android debugger and compilers configured with related NDK. (Generally others use **windows cdb debugger** and **i686** compiler)[image]
2. Change other kits' name and the warning signal will disappear:[image]
3. Find the profile in profiles.xml

`<value type="QString" key="PE.Profile.Name">Android Qt %{Qt:Version} Clang Multi-Abi--delete this</value>`  and delete entire data tag

4. Rename data tags `<variable>` in profiles.xml like Profile.0, Profile.1.
5. **DON'T FORGET** to change `<variable>Profile.count</variable>` tag according to your number of kits.

Cheers!

[image]